# How can I run functional tests from a django view?

Tags: python, django, testing, view, command

I would like to run the functional tests in the webpage using python,django. Can't I just use management.call_command like this in my views.py ?

```
call_command('test', 'folder.tests.Mytest')
```

Mytest inherits from TestCase of Selenium and contains the classic setUp() and test_() methods.
Here the error shown is:
"ValueError: signal only works in main thread"

Cannot the command be called from the views?

Thank you

Comment: I do not entirely follow what you want to do. Usually one can test views, etc. with `django-pytest`: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ It provides some extra usage to inspect the response, etc.

Comment: Usually you can just use `pytest` then, so it is a command (well not in `manage.py`, but that's more a detail I think).

Comment: Actually I want to ./manage.py test and show results in my web site in order to allow the web site users to run the tests via the site

Comment: When is the error triggering? You might want to include your views to demonstrate how you are going about this.